# Math Expression Parser

Tags: java, parsing

I found the code of Math Expression Parser from Dreamincode Forum.

My question is, on that code I think everything is going all right, but when I had a testcase '(2(3+5)' , that was valid, whereas this test case is completely wrong

but if I give the test case '(3+5)2)' it was detect as non valid input. 
Anyone knows why this is happening?

```
//enum for Operator "objects"
import java.util.*;

public enum Operator {

    ADD("+", 1)
    {
        double doCalc(double d1, double d2) {
            return d1+d2;
        }
    },
    SUBTRACT("-",1)
    {
        double doCalc(double d1, double d2) {
            return d1-d2;
        }
    },
    MULTIPLY("*", 2)
    {
        double doCalc(double d1, double d2) {
            return d1*d2;
        }
    },
    DIVIDE("/",2)
    {
        double doCalc(double d1, double d2) {
            return d1/d2;
        }
    },
    STARTBRACE("(", 0)
    {
        double doCalc(double d1, double d2) {
            return 0;
        }
    },
    ENDBRACE(")",0)
    {
        double doCalc(double d1, double d2) {
            return 0;
        }
    },
    EXP("^", 3)
    {
        double doCalc(double d1, double d2) {
            return Math.pow(d1,d2);
        }
    };

    private String operator;
    private int precedence;

    private Operator(String operator, int precedence) {
        this.operator = operator;
        this.precedence = precedence;
    }

    public int getPrecedenceLevel() {
        return precedence;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return operator;
    }

    public static boolean isOperator(String s) {
        for(Operator op : Operator.values()) { //iterate through enum values
            if (op.getSymbol().equals(s))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Operator getOperator(String s) 
        throws InvalidOperatorException {
            for(Operator op : Operator.values()) { //iterate through enum values
                if (op.getSymbol().equals(s))
                    return op;
            }
            throw new InvalidOperatorException(s + " Is not a valid operator!");
    }

    public boolean isStartBrace() {
        return (operator.equals("("));
    }
    //overriding calculation provided by each enum part
    abstract double doCalc(double d1, double d2);
}
//error to be thrown/caught in ProjectOne.java
class InvalidOperatorException extends Exception {
    public InvalidOperatorException() {
    }

    public InvalidOperatorException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}



//reading in a string at doing the parsing/arithmetic 
public static void main (String[] args) {
     String input = "";
     //get input
     System.out.print("Enter an infix exp<b></b>ression: ");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {                        
            input = in.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error getting input!");
        }

        doCalculate(input);
    }

    // Input: user entered string
    // Output: Display of answer
    public static void doCalculate(String equation) {
        //our stacks for storage/temp variables
        Stack<Operator> operatorStack;
        Stack<Double> operandStack;
        double valOne, valTwo, newVal;
        Operator temp;

        //initalize
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(equation, " +-*/()^", true);
        String token = "";
        operandStack = new Stack();
        operatorStack = new Stack();
        try {
                while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){ //run through the string
                    token = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    if (token.equals(" ")) { //handles spaces, goes back up top
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (!Operator.isOperator(token)){ //number check
                        operandStack.push(Double.parseDouble(token));
                    }
                    else if (token.equals("(")) {
                        operatorStack.push(Operator.getOperator(token));
                    }
                    else if (token.equals(")")) { //process until matching paraentheses is found
                        while (!((temp = operatorStack.pop()).isStartBrace())) {
                            valTwo = operandStack.pop();
                            valOne = operandStack.pop();
                            newVal = temp.doCalc(valOne, valTwo);
                            operandStack.push(newVal);
                        }
                    }
                    else { //other operators
                        while (true) { //infinite loop, check for stack empty/top of stack '('/op precedence
                            if ((operatorStack.empty()) || (operatorStack.peek().isStartBrace()) || 
                                (operatorStack.peek().getPrecedenceLevel() < Operator.getOperator(token).getPrecedenceLevel())) {
                                    operatorStack.push(Operator.getOperator(token));
                                    break; //exit inner loop
                            }
                            temp = operatorStack.pop();
                            valTwo = operandStack.pop();
                            valOne = operandStack.pop();
                            //calculate and push
                            newVal = temp.doCalc(valOne, valTwo);
                            operandStack.push(newVal);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperatorException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid operator found!");
            }

            //calculate any remaining items (ex. equations with no outer paraentheses)
            while(!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
                temp = operatorStack.pop();
                valTwo = operandStack.pop();
                valOne = operandStack.pop();
                newVal = temp.doCalc(valOne, valTwo);
                operandStack.push(newVal);
            }
            //print final answer
            System.out.println("Answer is: " + operandStack.pop()); 
        }
```

Comment: Two right parens but only one left?

Comment: Test your operand stack. Your second expression is found to be invalid because of the bad `)`. Your first expression *appears* valid but only because you get *a* result: "no more operators so the last value must be right".

Comment: you mean, (2(3+5) is valid input? but there are no operators between 2 and 3

Comment: I hope you take this as an example of how ***not*** to write an expression parser.  It's wrong on so many levels...

Comment: hmm.. could u mention the other wrong test case? mmm...

Comment: You said yourself this treats your `(2(3+5)` as "valid". The reason it "passes" is because you clear the operator stack but do not check what's left on the operand stack, which was why I suggested testing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This calculator does not work with implicit multiplication. you can use:

```
2((2+2)+1)
```

And see that it gives the wrong answer as opposed to:

```
2*((2+2)+1)
```

The false-positive expression you've used does not pass with explicit multiplication.

A quick for-the-lazy fix to add implicit multiplication would be something of that sort:

```
public static void doCalculate(String equation) {
            // make it explicit:
            System.out.println("Got:" + equation);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+|[a-z\\)])(?=[0-9]+|[a-z\\(])");
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(equation);
            System.out.println("Made it: "+ (equation = m.replaceAll("$1*")));
            //our stacks for storage/temp variables
            Stack<Operator> operatorStack;
            Stack<Double> operandStack;
            double valOne, valTwo, newVal;
            Operator temp;
```

This is an attempt to capture implicit multiplication using regex and make it explicit.

It fixes all cases we've come up with.

Comment: aha, but how to fix the implicit multiplication? is it wrong input or ?

Comment: *Fix* the implicit multiplication? It probably wasn't supposed to work to begin with I suppose. Perhaps you can *add* it.

Comment: Added quick fix. This is not tested and should be avoided at all costs :) If you ever fix it better, please answer your own question with the fix.

Comment: hmm, i found the other string that must be a problem.. for instance : ((1+3)5 they're valid.. :/ hmmh.. can i used ur pattern again to solve this one?

Comment: I've edited my answer with this pattern: "([0-9]+|[a-z\\)])(?=[0-9]+|[a-z\\(])". You can modify it after reading about regex and their use and practice.

Comment: owh, ok.. yesterday i found the tutorial of using pattern in Java. And the cases is closed :D , thanks

Comment: I'm trying to add implicit multiplication to [a parser](https://github.com/silentmatt/js-expression-eval), and I have just concluded that to make it properly you need to take order of operations into account.

Consider `2x^2x`, which if written by hand should be interpreted as `2*x^(2*x)` -- in the exponential you need parenthesis, but in the base you should _not_ have parenthesis.

(Maybe this isn't really about order of operations, but that our mathematical writing is inconsistent. Anyway, it seems that regexp won't solve it completely.)

Comment: The pattern suggested above is a bit too greedy when making replacements – '11x' becomes '1*1*x'.

I removed the numbers in the second part of the pattern, and it now works fine for all the cases I've tried. (Is there a purpose for those numbers that I haven't though of?)

Changing the comment/example to this:

`([0-9]+|[a-z\\)])(?=[a-z\\(])`