# Lexer Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, lexer

I'm new to Java and have to compile lexer from the arithmetic exression for further calculation. I found useful code to check, but there is one problem while analizing string. When i have something like: 5-9.3 it determines as:

```
NUMBER 5

NUMBER -9.3
```

instead of

```
NUMBER 5

ADDSUBSTR -

NUMBER 9.3
```

Don't know how to fix it. Would appreciate your help. Want to solve it because it would be harder to cope with it while calculating. And sorry for my awful typesetting.

```
public class Lexer {

    public static enum TokenType {

        NUMBER("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"), ADDSUBSTR("[+|-]"), DIVMULT ("[/|*]"), WHITESPACE("[ \t\f\r\n]+");
        public final String pattern;

        private TokenType(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }
    }


    public static class Token {
        public TokenType token;
        public String data;

        public Token (TokenType token, String data) {
            this.token = token;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s", token.name(), data);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Token> lexer(String s) {

        ArrayList<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

        StringBuffer tokenBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (TokenType tokenType : TokenType.values())
          tokenBuffer.append(String.format("|(?<%s>%s)", tokenType.name(), tokenType.pattern));
        Pattern tokenPatterns = Pattern.compile(new String(tokenBuffer.substring(1)));

        Matcher matcher = tokenPatterns.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
          if (matcher.group(TokenType.NUMBER.name()) != null) {
            tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.NUMBER, matcher.group(TokenType.NUMBER.name())));
          }
          else if (matcher.group(TokenType.ADDSUBSTR.name()) != null) {
            tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.ADDSUBSTR, matcher.group(TokenType.ADDSUBSTR.name())));
          } 
          else if (matcher.group(TokenType.DIVMULT.name()) != null) {
            tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.DIVMULT, matcher.group(TokenType.DIVMULT.name())));
          }
          else if (matcher.group(TokenType.WHITESPACE.name()) != null);
            }

    return tokens;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String input = in.nextLine();
            ArrayList<Token> tokens = lexer(input);
            for (Token token : tokens)
                System.out.println(token);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should do some debugging.

Comment: Also, rather than apologising for "awful typesetting", why not just format your code correctly? (You're more likely to get help that way) ;)

Comment: The logic in your code would allow for something like `1 +-/* 12 12 12 *****` - is that intentional?

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth i tried to debug, but it didn't get me closer to result. Just can't understand. Even if i place check for operator "+-" befor checking number pattern it still adds - to the number.

Comment: @ClasG i know it, i'm trying to solve problems when they occur, i'll watch for some chekups for it, but not now

Comment: Maybe [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912455/math-expression-parser) could be of interest for you...

Comment: ...or (depending what you're trying to achieve, i.e. if you're simply trying to calculate the value) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010674/looking-for-an-expression-evaluator).

Comment: @ClasG thanks for the links